# How to count rows by date for each of two values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large dataset in SQL Server that contains two date fields and a foreign key field (among others):

```
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+
| id | type_id | report_date | import_date |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2021-08-01  | 2021-08-02  |
|  2 |       1 | 2021-08-01  | 2021-08-02  |
|  3 |       2 | 2021-08-01  | 2021-08-02  |
|  4 |       2 | 2021-08-04  | 2021-08-05  |
|  5 |       1 | 2021-08-04  | 2021-08-05  |
|  6 |       3 | 2021-08-04  | 2021-08-05  |
|  7 |       2 | 2021-08-04  | 2021-08-04  |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need a query that can count the number of rows for each day, but to count them for each distinct value in the `type_id` column. The closest I can wrap my brain around right now is returning the total count of all rows for a particular date:

```
select count(REPORT_DATE) as records,
       REPORT_DATE        as report_date
from MY_TABLE
group by REPORT_DATE;
```

How do I split this up to return an additional column for each value of `type_id`? For example:

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
|    date    | count_1 | count_2 | count_3 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 2021-08-01 |       2 |       1 |       0 |
| 2021-08-04 |       1 |       2 |       1 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I assume I will need at least one subquery, but that is beyond my current knowledge.

Comment: What's expected to happen if type_id 4 shows up later?

Comment: Google `PIVOT`.

Comment: @jarlh - The query should account for potentially new values being in that column; I do not want to hard-code a value.

Comment: If you need the query to magically take on new values as soon as they appear in the table, no, neither example in my answer takes care of that - you'll need to change the query. If you need magic then look at [dynamic `PIVOT`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/).

Comment: The SQL language assumes you know how many columns your query will produce. If you don't know in advance you'll need to: 1) Run an initial query to find out how many distinct values are there, and 2) Assemble a Dynamic SQL query and run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `PIVOT` or a conditional aggregate.

PIVOT:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT report_date, type_id, c = COUNT(*) 
  FROM dbo.MY_TABLE
  GROUP BY report_date, type_id
)
SELECT report_date,
  count_1 = COALESCE([1], 0),
  count_2 = COALESCE([2], 0),
  count_3 = COALESCE([3], 0)
FROM src 
PIVOT (MAX(c) FOR type_id IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS p;
```

Conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT report_date,
  count_1 = SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  count_2 = SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  count_3 = SUM(CASE WHEN type_id = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM dbo.MY_TABLE
GROUP BY report_date;
```

Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2850cfbf1f033ee51583a7ff3095ccd1)

Use whichever one is more intuitive for you to learn and understand, though I will say conditional aggregate is certainly easier to maintain when, say, `type_id = 4` shows up later, as @jarlh suggested in a comment.